# Change element type on change detected in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a list of checkboxes with associated labels and the labels are tooltips and therefore defined as anchor tags. See images:

[image]
[image]

The way my checkbox list works is that when a checkbox is `checked`, it toggles an input to be shown to the right as shown above. However, on the last item in these checkbox is one called "Other". For this, is a change event is detected, I want to simply change the "Other" text to a `<input ="text" />` and modifying my existing working functions for all of this has me crossed and was hoping on input on how I can do this within the **same** `handleChange10` event as indicated in code below (my code snippets below to show all for this view, but just for the pieces in need of help on)?:

```
handleChange9() {
    this.setState({
      checked9: !this.state.checked9
    })
}

handleChange10() {
    this.setState({
      checked10: !this.state.checked10
    })
}

toggle9() {
    this.setState({
      tooltipOpen9: !this.state.tooltipOpen9
    });
}

const numberNeeded9 = this.state.checked9
  ? <Input type="text" className="flrt" id="addlInfo9" placeholder="how many" onChange={this.inputNumOfEx}></Input>
  : null;

const numberNeeded10 = this.state.checked10
  ? <Input type="text" className="flrt" id="addlInfo10" placeholder="how many" onChange={this.inputNumOfOth}></Input>
  : null;

<FormGroup check>
  <span className="flrt">{numberNeeded8}</span>
  <Label className="custType" check>
    <Input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked8} onChange={this.handleChange8} />
    <a id="custType8" className="custTypeTxt">Scientists</a>
    <Tooltip placement="right" isOpen={this.state.tooltipOpen8} target="custType8" toggle={this.toggle8}>
      Data, Research
   </Tooltip>
  </Label>
</FormGroup>

<FormGroup check>
  <span className="flrt">{numberNeeded10}</span>
  <Label className="custType" check>
    <Input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked10} onChange={this.handleChange10} />
    <a id="custType10" className="custTypeTxt">Other</a>
  </Label>
</FormGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<FormGroup check>
  <span className="flrt">{numberNeeded10}</span>
  <Label className="custType" check>
    <Input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.checked10} onChange={this.handleChange10} />
    {
      this.state.checked10? 
        <input type="text" /> :
        <a id="custType10" className="custTypeTxt">Other</a>
    }
  </Label>
</FormGroup>
```

But I don't think You should do it this way. You can keep in the state id of selected checkbox, and You will no need `handleChange1,2,3,4,5,6,7()`.